# How to use a monospaced font in the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard's SQL Statement?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, settings

How do I change the fonts used in the **TableAdapter Configuration Wizard** SQL Statement?

As you see here, the  alignment of the Query is wrong, so I want to set this box so it uses a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) like "Consolas" or "Courier New".

[image: TableAdapter Configuration Wizard]

I think I need to change something in **Tool - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors**:

[image: Tool - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors]

But I cannot find which setting/display item I need to select to change it. There's one named "Query and View Designer" but it (only) changes the font when you use the Query builder by clicking the "Query builder" button.

How do I do this? Do I need to change a setting somewhere else?

Comment: Why do you care about the alignment of the SQL statement? It'll work even if you write it all on one line, won't it?

Comment: @Martha Then when do you use carriage return in your [CSS](http://blog.riddle.pl/post/1204336832/single-line-css) code? (or C++, JavaScript, or [you name it]) It work even if you write it all on one line! It's for readability, of course.

Comment: Well, yeah, readability is why you don't write it all on one line, but readability doesn't require everything to line up perfectly. It's generally enough to start each statement on a new line, which you've already done.

Comment: @Martha Are you saying that you don't code using monospaced font? it's even written on it's [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) that it "*increases the readability of source code, which is often heavily reliant on distinctions involving individual symbols.*"

Comment: It's unclear whether this is possible. I often use SQL Management Studio in a separate window to design my queries; it's a much more full-featured editor in general. I'm not sure that's available or appropriate for what you're doing, but the wizard is never going to be a full-featured SQL environment.

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan I want this so the query is more readable out of the box. It's useful when I'm are just checking the query so I could quickly see if the problem is there, or just copy/pasting some change across multiple query (example a new column). If a more complete examination or debugging is needed, I then use a real editor.

Comment: I can certainly see the value of theming the wizard. I just wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible. That textbox isn't meant to be much of an editor. :-/

Comment: Delete every font from your PC except Courier.  Empty your recycler bin.  Reset your computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just ask Microsoft to add it in ;-)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657090/make-fonts-and-colors-query-and-view-designers-affect-tableadapter-configuration-wizard

Comment: so far, it's what sound the most promising to ever get a solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this wizard has a TextBox, probably in WPF since Visual Studio 2010 is mostly WPF.  Since Visual Studio has many hooks to support extensions, it is possible that an extension could be created. I would not use my time trying to find it--my gut is that down such a path lies much suffering.

Seems easier to leave open a SQL Management Studio query window (or a SQL syntax-highlighting text editor of your choice) on the side, then copy and paste as needed.